# Tootip and signal of Gio.MenuItem

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject

Below are two questions on the same component:

1. Which signal is triggered when the mouse passes over a `Gio.MenuItem`?
2. How to implement a tooltip for `Gio.MenuItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to get this was much further than I thought. I always suspected that the Devhelp's menu could not be built using GtkPopoverMenu because my OS uses gtk 3.14. The solution involves a totally new concept of running an application, proposed by Gtk.Application interface and the Gtk.Action features. These "new" concepts can be studied in the following places.

http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/application.html?highlight=Gtk.Application

https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/GtkApplication

https://github.com/Programmica/python-gtk3-tutorial/blob/master/_examples/application.py

Apparently tooltip features are not available for this menu type.

Answer (score 3):

`Gio.MenuItem` is a direct descendent from `GObject.GObject` (See https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gio-2.0/classes/MenuItem.html). It does not have any signals itself, and only receives a `notify` signal via its descent from GObject.

As `Gio.MenuItem` is not a widget, it does not receive any signals from the GUI. It only represents data (opaque data at that).

I suspect you want `Gtk.MenuItem`, which is the visual component.

**EDIT** It seems the widget you are after is `Gtk.PopoverMenu`. Just to be clear, Gio.MenuItem is not a visible item, which is why I replied as above. Gtk.PopoverMenu is a widget (widget = a *visible* item).

`PopoverMenu` is the visible widget, and [**you can see how it fits together with other widgets**](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/PopoverMenu.html). It inherits from `Popover`, which inherits from `Gtk.Bin`, `Gtk.Container` and finally from `Gtk.Widget`.

So, you have all the signals from those widgets, but those are for the 'complete' `Gtk.PopoverMenu`, not for the individual items.

According [**to this definition**](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/PopoverMenu.html), the individual items are `Gtk.ModelButton`s, so you might be able to access them that way.

Comment: Unfortunately GtkMenuItem does not have the same appearance as Gio.MenuItem :-\. For this reason I am using a Gio.MenuItem instead of a GtkMenuItem.

Comment: Can you show the part of the program where you actually use Gio.Menuitem?

Comment: My intention is to make a menu like [this](http://oi64.tinypic.com/dg3sq1.jpg).
This is the menu of `Devhelp` application

Comment: If I use GtkMenu and GtkMenuItem I get [this](http://oi67.tinypic.com/2n84k7c.jpg) appearance. That is, I get a squared menu without rounded corners

Comment: Thanks for taking some of your time to answer.
I saw in the documentation that GtkPopoverMenu is available from version 3.16 of GTK. But my OS (Debian 8.5) uses GTK 3.14.
Is there another way to get a menu like it?

Curiosity: If my operating system uses gtk 3.14, how the Devhelp application has a PopoverMenu?

The Devhelp's version is 3.14 too.

Comment: I downloaded the [Devhelp's code 3.14](http://ftp.gnome.org/mirror/gnome.org/sources/devhelp/3.14/) but still can not find the part of code related to PopoverMenu.

Comment: After a little more research, I found that Gio.Menu and Gio.MenuItem implement a "new" concept, a different concept of Gtk signals. This "new" concept is called Actions.
So if I want something to happen when a Gio.MenuItem is clicked I need to associate it to an Action.
In [an example](http://paste.debian.net/790265) I tried to implement an action for an GMenuItem, but is not working.

Comment: PopoverMenu is documented in [Lazca's PGI API](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/), particularly in [this place](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/PopoverMenu.html). This documentation is 'priceless', and very well updated. You can download it and browse it locally.

Comment: PopoverMenu does not fit my case because my version of GTK is 3.14.
I think the solution to this case is `Gio.Menu`, `Gio.MenuItem` using `Gio.SimpleAction`.
I created a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020511/understanding-the-concept-of-actions) about the Actions feature.

Comment: Actions are a way to centralize the code for several widgets. Eg. if you have a program, you typicially have a File menu, with an Open option. Then you have a toolbar with an 'Open' button. You can then make both point to the same Action to do the work.

Comment: I understand that actions are also the way you can give functionality to `GMenuItem`, since these do not use signs like Gtk components.
So I think I can use `GMenu` and `GMenuItem` to get the menu that I want. And give roles to `MenuItem` through actions.

But what's wrong with my [test](http://paste.debian.net/790301)?